# WRITEXML error in c#

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2010

Can anyone tell me what i'm doing wrong here.I am trying to generate a system info in xml.My XML schema is like this

```
<root>
   <system>
        <applications>
        </applications>
   </system>
</root>
```

Snooping around the internet i found this code.But it is hard to implement it
problems faced:
"b" is a string which i get from regedit.exe's version number

```
writer.WriteElementString("Execute Bit Length", "64");
```

Also doesn't work

```
writer.WriteStartElement(".Net Framework 4", NET_FRAMEWORK.ToString());
```

gives me the error cannot write hexadecimal value 0x20
 NET_FRAMEWORK is a boolean value.
Basically i screwed up with the XML

```
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("sys_info.xml"))
                {


                    writer.WriteStartDocument();
                    writer.WriteStartElement("System");



                    writer.WriteStartElement("OS");

                    writer.WriteElementString("Ver", Environment.OSVersion.ToString());
                    writer.WriteElementString("Execute Bit Length", "64");
                    writer.WriteElementString("Registry version", b.ToString());


                    writer.WriteEndElement();

                    writer.WriteStartElement("APPCHECK");
                    writer.WriteStartElement(".Net Framework 4", NET_FRAMEWORK.ToString());
                    writer.WriteStartElement("PDF reader", PDF_READ.ToString());
                    writer.WriteStartElement("internet Explorer Version", IE.ToString());
                    writer.WriteEndElement();
                    writer.WriteEndDocument();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that spaces are not allowed in XML node names, so you need to change or remove them.

Also I would recommend you to try Linq to XML:

```
var xDocument = new XDocument(
    new XElement("root", 
        new XElement("System", 
            new XElement("OS",
                new XElement("Ver", Environment.OSVersion.ToString()), 
                new XElement("Execute_Bit_Length", "64"),
                new XElement("Registry_version", b) 

                ),
            new XElement("APPCHECK",
                new XElement("NET_Framework_4", NET_FRAMEWORK),
                new XElement("PDF_Reader", PDF_READ),
                new XElement("Internet_Explorer_Version", IE)
            )
        )));

xDocument.Save("sys_info.xml");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work as you cannot use values with spaces and punctuation in `WriteStartElement` and in first argument of `WriteElementString`. Also for each `WriteStartElement` you need to add `WriteEndElement`.

Comment: writer.WriteElementString("Ver", Environment.OSVersion.ToString()); runs fine though

Comment: @user1235546 That's because "Ver" does not contain spaces and punctuation which cannot be used in first argument of `WriteElementString` (is it clear from text of my answer above?).